# License of ASP.NET MVC 3 jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, licensing

I was wondering if I am allowed to use in any of my projects the [jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js) or [jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js) script that comes with ASP.NET MVC 3? Or are there any limitations?

Namely the script contains only this comment:

> ** Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

According to my knowledge this means that no one is allowed to do anything with this script without explicit permission from Microsoft (ie. use it, redistribute it, modify it combine it with other scripts, sublicense it...). Or is there any other license that comes with ASP.NET MVC 3 or Visual Studio that overrides this?

Am I allowed to use it in web pages developed with Visual Studio - commercial and non-commercial ones? What about in web pages that do not run on Microsoft's technology and what about those not even developed in any of Microsoft's products?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering to myself:

The license of ASP.NET MVC 3 is in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\eula.rtf` which states that any distributable code can be used as part of ASP.NET programs (that run on Windows platform).